# Make Flutter Container Responsive

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make an app and I have used a container and a column widget under a stack widget but the width of the container and the positioned widget of a column widget are not updating according to the screen sizes.

**Screenshot:**

[image]
[image]

Please check the demo code given below and re-edit the code. Thank you.

**code**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Center(
      child: Container(
          height: 135,
          width: width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              'https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/82317.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              height: 120,
                              width: 120,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 5, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: width * 0.6,
                        height: 110,
                        child: const Text(
                          'product.name',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 80,
                left: width * 0.85,
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      'Rs200',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Rs300',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: give me some time currently outside, I'll fix it. :P

Comment: will wait for your reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*First of all, you have used so many redundant widgets which do not serve any purpose except making the code look ugly and complex. I have refactored the code and have used the least number of widgets while fulfilling your requirement:*

**Demo on the action**: https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=75d503fcbe2bdb0e8b37ff21fc284a30

**Gist link:** https://gist.github.com/omishah/75d503fcbe2bdb0e8b37ff21fc284a30 ( *Do give star if this works for you. :)* )

I have made the image also responsive which you can remove if you don't want to have it.

**Complete code:**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
        body: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(
          8.0), // just to make the contianer stand out, you can remove it

      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.network(
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height:
                  width * 0.25, // 25% of screen width
              width: width * 0.25,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Expanded(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                Text(
                  'product.name',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Wrap(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
                      Text(
                        'Rs200',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Rs300',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                            fontSize: 17,
                            color: Colors.blueGrey),
                      ),
                    ]))
              ])),
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: you have done a really great job sir. Thank you very very much. I have few more queries can you please help . Thank you once again. and I don't know how to give a 5* sorry.

Comment: What problem? Say.

Comment: Please check this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495139/how-to-implement-search-bar-using-multiple-firestore-collections

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        height: 135,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.network(
                            'https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/82317.jpg',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            height: 120,
                            width: 120,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 15, 5, 0),
                    child: Container(
                      
                      height: 110,
                      child: const Text(
                        'product.name',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 80,
              right: 20,
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    'Rs200',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Rs300',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                        fontSize: 17,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

And your screen look like this - [image]

Comment: thank you for your expensive reply but its not working. Thank you once again.

Comment: that problem has been solved . Thank you for your expensive time sir. Thank you very much.

Comment: that problem has been solved by someone else, If you can help please help me solving these two problem given below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495139/how-to-implement-search-bar-using-multiple-firestore-collections                                               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68431803/how-to-download-video-flutter-app-in-your-gallery

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use of any Stack. I think you can do things using  the row and column widget, check out the example that I have added below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            height: 135,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(
                          'https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/82317.jpg',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          height: 120,
                          width: 120,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 5, 0),
                              child: const Text(
                                'asdfnweoriwqer qweroiqwoer qweruqwoer sadfsdf dfsdf ',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  'Rs200',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Rs300',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Layout explanation:

1. There will be one row which will have two items 1) image and another will be a column.
2. Now the Column will have expanded widget to get max width.
3. Column children will have two row widget one product name and another price row which will have Column as widget for text.
4. we have used row to take the max width.

For the Text to expand accordingly you have to add the expanded widget inside the row widget so that it scales based on the text that is coming.

You will have to add padding according to your need.

Comment: Earlier I had used it the way u did but when I tried to add very lengthy product name it went offscreen that's why I had to wrap stack widget to a container widget with child product name and with a certain width to shift the lengthy text to the next line.

Comment: So if you have lengthy product name then you can add a row to the text so that it can resize accordingly

Comment: please help if u can .

Comment: @NitishGarg please check if have updated the code for the produt name

Comment: still showing the same error.  'A RenderFlex overflowed by 354 pixels on the right.
'

Comment: how much lengthy is the text, can you add a picture. From my study it is believed that that product name should not be that big enough, you should limit the user when they specify the product name, and the if you want to you can add the separate parameter to to describe the product.

Comment: If not, are you using this one tile in the listview or what, because you are specifying height for the tile it will show the overflow error.

Comment: that problem has been solved thank you very very much for your expensive time sir. I do have more queries that I have posted on stack but no one is replying can you please help. I shall be thank full to you. Thank you once again.

Comment: hey there, still waiting for your reply.

Comment: Can you send me the link for that

Comment: Here are the links-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495139/how-to-implement-search-bar-using-multiple-firestore-collections , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68431803/how-to-download-video-flutter-app-in-your-gallery.

Comment: hey there! still waiting for your response. Please reply.