# how to implement search bar using multiple firestore collections

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

*Hello there, I am trying to make an ecommerce app with four different categories(bedsheets, computers, doormat sand products) and separate collections are created for each single category on firestore which share same field names, please check the image here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad974.jpg). Now I want to implement search by product name operation from my home page but I only know how to implement search for single firestore collection. Please check and help me, I am new to flutter please explain in details and if possible edit code given below. Thank you.*

**product service**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/modals/product_modal.dart';
class ProductServices {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

 
  Future<List<ProductModal>> searchProducts({String productName}) {
    // code to convert the first character to uppercase
    String searchKey = productName[0].toUpperCase() + productName.substring(1);
    return _firestore
        .collection('products')
        .orderBy("name")
        .startAt([searchKey])
        .endAt([searchKey + '\uf8ff'])
        .get()
        .then((result) {
          List<ProductModal> products = [];
          for (DocumentSnapshot product in result.docs) {
            products.add(ProductModal.fromSnapshot(product));
          }
          return products;
        });
  }
}
```

**product provider**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/modals/product_modal.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/services/product_service.dart';

class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ProductServices _productServices = ProductServices();
 
  List<ProductModal> productsSearched = [];


  Future search({String productName}) async {
    productsSearched = await _productServices.searchProducts(
         productName: productName);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**search Bar implementation**

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 10),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink[100]),
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                ),
                title: TextField(
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                  onSubmitted: (pattern) async {
                    await productProvider.search(productName: pattern);
                    changeScreen(context, ProductSearchScreen());
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "search...",
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**search screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/common.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/providers/product_provider.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/screens/cart.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/screens/products_screen/details_page.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/screens/products_screen/products_page.dart';

class ProductSearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }),
        title: Text(
          "Result",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {
                changeScreen(
                  context,
                  Cart(),
                );
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: productProvider.productsSearched.length < 1
          ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "No products Found",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          fontSize: 22),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: productProvider.productsSearched.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      changeScreen(
                          context,
                          ProductDetails(
                              products:
                                  productProvider.productsSearched[index]));
                    },
                    child: SingleProduct(
                        product: productProvider.productsSearched[index]));
              }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey can you please help me solving this problem.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: please read the description. I have mentioned everything in the description.

Comment: That's not a problem, that's a requirement !!

Comment: First, you try to implement yourself, and if it's not working then we're here to help. :)

Comment: I have tried everything sir. I also tried passing a string variable as collection in product service screen in searchproduct method but nothing is working. Please help.